# Help understanding polynomial modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started doing cryptography and currently im doing AES and got involved with the Galois Fields $GF(2^m)$. The question is regarding the multiplications and I am stuck in reducing the terms $x^4$ and $x^5$. Could someone please explain how it works? Also notably my teacher did long division directly and I tried as well but the result is not the same.
[image: Image for reference]

Comment: What was the result you obtained?

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind reduction is same for polynomials as it is for the numbers. For example, when you are working say $\mod 5$ and want to multiply $7$ and $11$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, you will do the following:
$$7 \times 11  \equiv (\color{red}{5}+2) \times (\color{red}{5(2)}+1) \equiv (\color{red}{0}+2)(\color{red}{0}+1) \equiv 2 \pmod{5}.$$
The basic idea is that for the reduction we will keep using $5 \equiv 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Now coming to the $GF(2^4)$, here we will use that $P(x) \equiv 0$ (and of course $2 \equiv 0$) for the reduction.

**A few observations**:
\begin{align*}
x^4 +x+1 & \equiv 0 \\
 x^4 & \equiv -x-1\\
x^4 & \equiv x+1 & (\because 2 \equiv 0)
\end{align*}
Now consider,
\begin{align*}
(x^3+x^2+1)(x^2+x) &\equiv x^5+ 2x^4 +x^3+x^2+x\\
& \equiv x(\color{red}{x^4})+ \color{red}{0}+x^3+x^2+x & (\because 2 \equiv 0)\\
& \equiv x(\color{red}{x+1})+ x^3+x^2+x & (\because x^4 \equiv x+1)\\
& \equiv x^3+2x^2+2x\\
& \equiv x^3.
\end{align*}

---

To take up another example,
\begin{align*}
(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1) &\equiv x^6+ x^5+x^4 +3x^3+x^2+x+1\\
& \equiv x^2(\color{red}{x^4})+ x(\color{red}{x^4})+ x^4+\color{red}{1}x^3+x^2+x & (\because 2 \equiv 0)\\
&\equiv \color{red}{x^4}(x^2+x+1)+x^3+x^2+x \\
& \equiv (\color{red}{x+1})(x^2+x+1)+ x^3+x^2+x & (\because x^4 \equiv x+1)\\
& \equiv 2x^3+3x^2+3x+1\\
& \equiv x^2+x+1.
\end{align*}

Comment: I understand that P(x)= x^4+x+1 . And also in Wikipedia it says that a^4=a+1. What i don't understand is how this a^4=a+1 works. What's the logic behind it? Maybe i am misunderstanding something but it's what caused confusion to me. Many  thanks!

Comment: @Stefan I have provided an explanation for that in the beginning under "few observations". In case of $5 \equiv 0$ we can write this as $3+2 \equiv 0$. So in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, we can say $3 \equiv -2$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).